# Get value from another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

We are using an application that runs on asp.net and C#. When a user is logged in, their profile information is displayed (name, id number) on a Profile page (information comes from MSSQL). I would like to get the id number for the logged in user and pass that value to an embedded form (this part I know I can do), the struggle is figuring out how to get the id number from one page to the other page.

I am not proficient with C# or asp.net but I did find where the id value is at, I am not sure how to call it from my form page?

Comment: Are you using web forms or MVC?

Comment: kind of confusing. "the struggle is figuring out how to get the id number from one page to the other page." what other page? "I did find where the id value is at, I am not sure how to call it from my form page." "get the id number for the logged in user and pass that value to an embedded form (this part I know I can do)."  hard to tell what you can and can't do and what you really want to do.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by an embedded form?

Answer (score 1):

**[Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Forms Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)**

The following options are available even if the source page is in a different ASP.NET Web application from the target page, or if the source page is not an ASP.NET Web Forms page:

- Use a query string
- Get HTTP POST information from the source page

The following options are available only when the source and target pages are in the same ASP.NET Web application:

- Use session state
- Create public properties in the source page and access the property
  values in the target page
- Get control information in the target page from controls in the
  source page

The main factor that should influence your approach should be the fact that this is a secure application and you do not want the information being passed to be prone to scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

First Option:

Use Cookies

On your firstPage.aspx

```
HttpCookie appCookie = new HttpCookie("IdValue");
appCookie.Value = "The value of your id here" or id.ToString();
appCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(appCookie);
```

To get:

SecondPage.aspx

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["IdValue"];
String getValue = aCookie.Value.ToString();
```

Cookies expires depends on your Settings here `appCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);` it can be AddDays('MoreNumberofdays') like `AddDays(4)` it will expires in 4 days. Something like that.

some additional  [Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)

Second Option:

Class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string storevalue;
}
```

Page1.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Class1.storevalue = "This is the value from page1";
            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");

}
```

Page2.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string getvalue = Class1.storevalue;
        }
```