# How do I pass a session storage value into a text box on page load before a pageload event from codebehind gets fired

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Javascript function which stores an Idnumber in localstorage on form1  and retrieves the localstorage data into a textbox on form2 when is loaded.

Everything works correctly but on the form2 I also have a codebehind which has to select a data from SQL database using the IDnumber in the textbox OnPageload event but it does not work.

So I realized when from2 is loaded the codebehind (onpageload)event get fired first before the Javascript which suppose to get the Idnumber into the text box.  please I am stuck and I don't know what to do again any help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem is I need the java script to get fired to load the Idnumber into the textbox before the sever side code get fired

This is my javascript on form1

```
    $(document).on("click", ".Laundry-Cont", function () {
        var classval =  $(this).children("input").val();
       // var getInput = prompt("Hey type something here: ");

     sessionStorage.setItem("storageName", classval);
       $(document.getElementById('<%=mnn.ClientID%>')).val(sessionStorage.getItem("storageName"));
      //  window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("storageName"));

      //$('#mn').val(localStorage.getItem("storageName"));
        window.location.href = '/proudctselection.aspx'
    });

 //this is my script on form2


 $(document.getElementById('<%=txtpicproductid.ClientID%>')).val(sessionStorage.getItem("storageName"));

   });

  //this is my SQL query on form2 in codebehind
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.Close()
    End If

    Dim selproduct As New SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM allproducts WHERE ItID = @productid")
    selproduct.Connection = cn
    selproduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = iidd


    Dim selproductda As New SqlDataAdapter(selproduct)
    Dim selproductdt As New DataTable
    selproductda.Fill(selproductdt)
    For Each rw As DataRow In selproductdt.Rows
        Me.productmainimage.ImageUrl = rw.Item(6).ToString


    Next

    cn.Close()
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to work as the page has to load completely before the JavaScript is displayed so you cannot get the JavaScript to run before the Page On Load Event.

You could pass the ID to the form 2 in a few different ways:

- Post the Value and Retrieve via Request.Form on page Load
- Pass via QueryString once done with Form 1 .. just Direct to Next Form with Querystring value
- Load the ID to a cookie and pull via Request.Cookies
- Depending on Data Requirement and display use AJAX / WebAPI / WebMethod and JavaScript to load necessary data after the page has loaded.
- Use Session State
- Create public properties in the source page and access the property values in the target page
- Get control information in the target page from controls in the source page

Might also want to review for more tips and ideas:  [Get value from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453743/get-value-from-another-page)

Comment: thanks very much my problem is solved now I passed the value via query string with javascript and retrieved it through code behind with request.query string